# Using String.replace() on more then one subject in one line

Tags: elixir

I have something like this:

```
 [element, object | _rest] ->
    [element, object |> String.replace("-", "_")]
    [element |> String.replace("-", "_"), object]
```

How can I compress this into one line with using String.replace() only once?

I will be grateful for help!

Comment: The code shown discards `[element, object |> String.replace("-", "_")]` expression. Please specify what you have as an input and what do you expect to get back as the outcome.

Comment: element is a string and object is a string. Example input -> [example-element, example-object | _rest] . Example output ->  example_element, example_object

Comment: `[element |> String.replace("-", "_"), object |> String.replace("-", "_")]` or `[element, object] |> Enum.map(&String.replace(&1, "-", "_")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#map/2) to transform a list where each element is the result of a given function.

```
[element, object | _rest] ->
  Enum.map([element, object], &String.replace(&1, "-", "_"))
```